# The way to configure n points that results in the maximum number of lines that contain at least m points?

Tags: combinatorics

I was thinking of the question described below when designing a program that can find the collinear lines in a plane.
https://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall12/cos226/checklist/collinear.html

If provided with $n$ points, what is the maximum number of lines which contain at least $m$ collinear points?

For instance, if $20$ points are provided, what is the maximum possible number of lines (and the corresponding configuration of these points that results in the maximum number of lines) which contains at least 4 points.

Please give me a combinatorial answer if possible. Thanks.

Comment: Have you attempted to solve this question yourself? If so, what where the obstacles to get a definitive answer?

Comment: Didn't you just post the [same question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4189723/whats-the-maximum-number-of-collinear-sets-of-points-in-a-set-of-n-points-in-th) half an hour ago?

Comment: Maybe this would help? https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2012/08/24/on-sets-defining-few-ordinary-lines/

Comment: @polygonlink1 Thank you so much.